# Creating a metric from a pseudometric

Tags: metric-spaces, proof-verification

Given the following definition of a pseudo-metric on the set $X$ :

A **pseudo-metric** on the set $X$ is a map $d:X \times X \to \Bbb R^+$ such that for all $x ,y \text{ and } z \in X :$

(PM1) $x=y \Rightarrow d(x,y)=0 $

(PM2) $d(x,y) =d(y,x)$

(PM3) $d(x,y) \le d(x,z) +d(z,y)$

We defined the following equivalence relation ~ on $X$ as 
$$ x \sim y \iff  d(x,y)= 0$$

We then proceeded to define $\delta$ as follows. For any $x,y \in X$

$$ \delta([x],[y]) = d(x,y)$$

I have to show that $\delta $ is a metric on the set of equivalence classes on $X$

I am busy with (M3)  and would like to know whether this is enough to show that $\delta $satifies M3:

$$\delta ([x],[y]) = d(x,y)$$
$$\leq d(x,z) +d (z,y) \text{    by PM3}$$
$$= \delta([x],[z]) + \delta ([y],[z])$$

Comment: After you have shown that $\delta$ is well-defined, that is enough to prove $M_3$.

Comment: would the final line not be an equality? it seems fine to me though.

Comment: @DanielFischer I have show that $\delta$ is well defined

Comment: Then you're done.